# (HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'!! flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, httpexception

Im trying to request JSONs and some images. The JSONs come just fine, as they are small. When im requesting images, I just get the following SocketException 95% of the time:

```
I/flutter ( 9249): Exception: type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'!!
```

On the server side it always appears with the status code 200. Sometimes the image does come threw and it works fine, but thats a rare event.
This is the code for the request that is not working:

```
static Future<Uint8List> productImage(int imageID) async {
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode("${Request.token}:"));

    http.Response response;
    http.Client client = http.Client();

    try {
      response = await client.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("$serverURL/inStoreProduct/getProductImage/$imageID"),
        headers: <String, String>{'Authorization': basicAuth},
      );
    } catch (SocketException) {
      print(
          "Exception: ${SocketException.toString()}!! Route: $serverURL/inStoreProduct/getProductImage/$imageID");
      return null;
    }
    print(
        "Route: $serverURL/inStoreProduct/getProductImage/$imageID -> ${response.statusCode}");
    if (response.statusCode != 200) return null;
    return response.bodyBytes;
  }
```

I've tried everything, I have another project that works just fine and everything is exactly the same. Any idea why the connection is beeing broken?

Edit:
here's the function call :
`var imgBytes = await InStoreRequests.productImage(imageID);`

Comment: Have u tried awaiting the image? Can ya share that code

Comment: var imgBytes = await InStoreRequests.productImage(imageID);
    if (imgBytes != null) 
      print("sucess");


I already await for the image, which is why this is so weird

Comment: try remove SocketException from the catch and just put catch(e){print("$e")} to see whats wrong! it looks like you are not managing correctly your exception

Comment: I/flutter (10205): Exception: type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'!!

same error shows up

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the call of `productImage()`.

### Wrong function call

In case your call look something like this:

```
image = productImage(imageId);
```

### Solution

Just add `await` to your call. Like explained in https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await.

```
image = await productImage(imageId);
```

If you make your function asynchronous, you always have to add `await` to wait the function to complete. Because of async your app will not wait till your function completes and just going to proceed with the next code.

Edit:
Have not seen the exception. Wrong answer.

Comment: var imgBytes = await productImage(imageID);
already done that, still doenst work

Comment: Try to run your app with `flutter run --verbose` for more information.

Comment: Already did, when I request the image isnt printing anything else new

[   +2 ms] I/flutter (10025): Exception: type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'!!

Comment: Maybe the stacktrace provide some more information to you. Use `catch(e, s) {print("$s")}`

Comment: this appears and some more that doesnt fit the comment

`I/flutter (10205): Exception: #0      _invokeErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:18:23)
I/flutter (10205): #1      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:288:9)
I/flutter (10205): #2      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:170:13)
I/flutter (10205): #3      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)
I/flutter (10205): #4      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
`

Answer (score 0):

Okey, turns out i'm dumb. It doesn't work properly on Android Studio, I tested it on a phone, and it worked just fine